# swfupload HTTP ERROR HTTP Status: 302

Tags: swfupload, http-status-code-302, http-error

i have a problem with swfupload, it always return HTTP ERROR  HTTP Status: 302 when i using FF, but work fine in other browser.

```
SWF DEBUG: SWFUpload Init Complete
SWF DEBUG: 
SWF DEBUG: ----- SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: Version:                2.5.0 2010-03-05 Beta 3.2
SWF DEBUG: movieName:              SWFUpload_0
SWF DEBUG: Upload URL:             http://localhost/administrator/upload
SWF DEBUG: File Types String:      *.*
SWF DEBUG: Parsed File Types:      
SWF DEBUG: HTTP Success:           0
SWF DEBUG: File Types Description: All Files (*.*)
SWF DEBUG: File Size Limit:        3145728 bytes
SWF DEBUG: File Upload Limit:      100
SWF DEBUG: File Queue Limit:       100
SWF DEBUG: Post Params:
SWF DEBUG: ----- END SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: 
SWF DEBUG: Stage Resize:64 by 23
SWF DEBUG: Button Image Loaded
SWF DEBUG: Stage Resize:64 by 23
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogStart : Browsing files. Multi Select. Allowed file types: *.*
SWF DEBUG: Select Handler: Received the files selected from the dialog. Processing the file list...
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileQueued : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogComplete : Finished processing selected files. Files selected: 1. Files Queued: 1
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload: First file in queue
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadStart : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload(): Upload Type: Normal.
SWF DEBUG: ReturnUploadStart(): File accepted by startUpload event and readied for standard upload.  Starting upload to http://localhost/administrator/upload for File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress (OPEN): File ID: SWFUpload_0_0 Bytes: 0. Total: 80202
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 80202. Total: 80202
**SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadError: HTTP ERROR : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. HTTP Status: 302.**
EXCEPTION: fileName: http://localhost/js/upload/fileprogress.js
EXCEPTION: lineNumber: 51
EXCEPTION: columnNumber: 2
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadComplete : Upload cycle complete.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [swfupload 302 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488110/swfupload-302-error)

Answer (score 0):

What you see here is a response from the server. And 302 means redirect. Check why your server is redirecting when uploading in the firefox.

I see you are using URL without trailing slash:

```
http://localhost/administrator/upload
```

some servers redirect to proper location by adding slash. Try upload to:

```
http://localhost/administrator/upload/
```

Comment: Do you have a live demo? You can use fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) to verify how is that upload request different from requests made in other browsers.

Comment: Hi @TomasKirda Bro I am having exactly the same issue on my side too and unable to solve it. can you help?