# 302 error when uploading file with SWFUpload in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, swfupload

I am using Swfupload to upload images. but it shows `error 302` only in firefox. it uploads fine with Chrome.

```
          upload1 = new SWFUpload({
    // Backend Settings
    upload_url: "/Articles/Photos.aspx?FolderName=" + FolderName,


    // File Upload Settings
    file_size_limit: "1024*5", // 5MB
    file_types: "*.bmp; *.gif; *.jpeg; *.jpg; *.png;",
    file_types_description: "Image Files",
    file_upload_limit: "10",
    file_queue_limit: "0",

    // Event Handler Settings (all my handlers are in the Handler.js file)
    file_dialog_start_handler: fileDialogStart,
    file_queued_handler: fileQueued,
    file_queue_error_handler: fileQueueError,
    file_dialog_complete_handler: fileDialogComplete,
    upload_start_handler: uploadStart,
    upload_progress_handler: uploadProgress,
    upload_error_handler: uploadError,
    upload_success_handler: uploadSuccess1,
    upload_complete_handler: uploadComplete,
    // Button Settings
    button_image_url: "../Images/XPButtonUploadText_61x22.png",
    button_placeholder_id: "spanButtonPlaceholder1",
    button_width: 61,
    button_height: 22,
    // Flash Settings
    flash_url: "/SWFUploader/swfupload.swf",


    custom_settings: {
        progressTarget: "fsUploadProgress1",
        cancelButtonId: "btnCancel1"
    },

    // Debug Settings
    debug: false
});
```

I am not sure what is causing this error..

Comment: @Sprottenwels .. answer me!!

Comment: @11684 where are you??

Comment: possible duplicate of [swfupload 302 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488110/swfupload-302-error)